# Consequence of commutating mapd on group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group; consider the mappings $\lambda_g:G\to G$ and $\tau_g:G\to G$, defined for $g\in G$ by $\lambda_g(x)=gx$ and $\tau_g(x)=xg$ for all $x\in G$.  If $\theta$ is a one-to-one mapping of $G$ onto itself such that $\lambda_g\theta=\theta\lambda_g$ for all $g\in G$, prove that $\theta=\tau_h$ for some $h\in G$.

**Proof:**  For any $g\in G$ we have $\lambda_g\theta=\theta\lambda_g$. So for any $x\in G$ we have $\lambda_g\theta(x)=\theta\lambda_g(x)$ or $g\theta(x)=\theta(gx)$. If we put $x=e$ we see that $\theta(g)=g\theta(e)$ and this relation is true for any $g\in G$. Thus $\theta(g)=\tau_{\theta(e)}(g)$ for any $g\in G$. Therefore, $\theta=\tau_h$ on $G$ where $h=\theta(e)$.

**Remark:** I guess that this problem is trivial and I saw it's duplicate in forum but I have decided not to look at that. So please do not close my topic. However, I spent approximately 1.5 hours in order to come up with solution. Is this solution correct?

Comment: You should compare your solution to the one of the [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355595/showing-a-map-multiplies-its-argument-by-some-element-on-the-right?rq=1) first yourself. It is exactly the argument with "letting $e$ be the identity" in the relation. So???

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I know that link but I have decided not to look at this link. I will take a look if somebody will comment my solution.

Comment: Just have a look and you have your answer yourself. So trust yourself; don't rely on others with understanding.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I took a look but some moments of those solution is not unclear to me. For example, how did he derived that $\theta(x)$ has the form $\theta(x)=xh$. However, in my solution I did not use the bijectivity of $\theta$. So it would be great if anyone check my solution

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I guess that you are completely right. But I did not use bijectivity and this confuses me.

Comment: You have used bijectivity, by using $\lambda_g\theta=\theta\lambda_g$. Because this gives, as you have shown, $\theta=\tau_h$, which is bijective, since it is a right multiplication on $G$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, i have read your last comment many times but can not get you. If we have not the condition of bijectivity then we would get the same result. I do not understand in what moment of my proof i have used bijectivity.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, if $\lambda_g\theta=\theta\lambda_g$ it means that two mapping have the same effect on $G$ so they are equal on $e$. Then i derived that $\theta$ has needed form. Since it is right multiplication then it is bijective. Instead of using bijecticity i have shown that $\theta$ bijective!

Comment: Yes, your proof also showed that such a map $\theta$ commuting with all the bijections $\lambda_g$ must be bijective. Isn't this nice?